OpenSearch with Spring Boot - Displaying docuemnts by number of keywors
I want to get OpenSearch results sorted (in descending order) by the number of keywords in the document. _score isn't what I am looking for. This one uses the BM25 algorithm, which is more like ranking with NLP techniques.
Example: I am searching for 2 phrases, 'happy' and 'cat'
What I have: I am getting documents sorted by _score (which is not what I want - as the long text with 5 keywords is ranked lower than a short document with 2 keywords)
What I want: I want the long document with 5 keywords to be at the top and the document with 2 keywords to be below.
My solution now:
I have a Java code solution for it, but that creates a bottleneck for the API. I am basically counting keywords words and then sorting documents by the number of keywords. That takes 2 parallel streams. I'm still blocking API for way too long. I am searching for a 'pure' OpenSearch solution.

Could you give some examples of documents that the scores that they should be generated and explain why? I am not sure if when you say "I want the long document with 5 keywords to be at the top" if you are talking about keywords that match your phrase or just any keywords in the field or something else.

I found the solution myself. I had to change the standard Okapi BM25 algorithm setting to one below. This has to be done when creating index.
BM25 params:

k1 - is a tuning parameter (usually set between 1.2 and 2.0) it controls the term frequency saturation. Increasing k1 increases the saturation effect.

b - is another tuning parameter (usually set around 0.75) – it controls the length normalization. A value of 1.0 fully normalizes document length, while 0.0 ignores length normalization.
 {
 "settings": {
 "index": {
   "similarity": {
     "default": {
       "type": "BM25",
       "k1": 2.0,
       "b": 0.0
     }
   }
 }

}


